# requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL Python API Get request

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib, urllib2

I am trying to pull the data using get request through the below URL and I'm getting below error.

I'm not understanding what is the issue with the URL.

Any help would be appreciated

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 
import json
import urllib.parse

url = """https://msi.abc.com/admin/ui/feedbackCSV/reports
/5d14de32309baf0001501fb7 ?reports[]=pageviews&reports[]=
searches&from=Oct 1 2020&to=Oct 2 2020"""

encode_url = urllib.parse.quote(url,encoding='utf-8')

response = requests.get(encode_url,auth = HTTPBasicAuth('admin@abc.com', 'Summer2020')) 
print(response.content)
```

**Error**

raise MissingSchema(error)
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'https%3A%2F%2Fmsi.abc.com%2Fadmin%2Fui%2FfeedbackCSV%2Freports%0D%0A%2F5d14de32309baf0001501fb7%20%3Freports%5B%5D%3Dpageviews%26reports%5B%5D%3D%0D%0Asearches%26from%3DOct%201%202020%26to%3DOct%202%202020': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:https%3A%2F%2Fmsi.abc.com%2Fadmin%2Fui%2FfeedbackCSV%2Freports%0D%0A%2F5d14de32309baf0001501fb7%20%3Freports%5B%5D%3Dpageviews%26reports%5B%5D%3D%0D%0Asearches%26from%3DOct%201%202020%26to%3DOct%202%202020?

Comment: How is the Output URL should look like? Can you put an example?

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe I  have this url https://msi.abc.com/admin/ui/feedbackCSV/reports
/5d14de32309baf0001501fb7 ?reports[]=pageviews&reports[]=
searches&from=Oct 1 2020&to=Oct 2 2020                                      i'm encoding this url to parse special char in uri using urllib.parse.quote(url,encoding='utf-8')

Comment: Okay. Is the host name 'msi.abc.com' a correct one or you just add it as an example?

Comment: I added it as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be due to that you pass the whole URL to the `urllib.parse.quote` function. Try passing the params only to the `urllib.parse.quote` or use `requests` params like in the below example:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 
import json
import urllib.parse

url = "https://msi.abc.com/admin/ui/feedbackCSV/reports/5d14de32309baf0001501fb7"
payload = {'reports[]':'pageviews', 'reports[]':'searches','from':'Oct 1 2020', 'to':'Oct 2 2020' }

authParams = HTTPBasicAuth('admin@abc.com', 'Summer2020')

response = requests.get(url,params=payload, auth =authParams ) 
print(response.content)
```